# Azure Kubernetes LB annotations

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, istio, azure-aks

The kubernetes official documentation for Service objects has some annotations regarding connection-draining, timeout, additional-tags etc. but these are limited to AWS.

I was hoping to find out the same for K8S deployment on Azure cloud.

For example,

```
 annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-connection-draining-enabled: "true"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-connection-draining-timeout: "60"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-connection-draining-timeout: "300"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-connection-idle-timeout: "600"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-healthcheck-healthy-threshold: "2"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-healthcheck-interval: "6"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-healthcheck-timeout: "5"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-healthcheck-unhealthy-threshold: "3"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: 0.0.0.0/0
```

From the [official documentation listed here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#connection-draining-on-aws)

If not such annotations exist, can someone help me achieve the same on Azure cloud. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the answer provided by kavyasaraboju-MT was helpful for you ? if so could you please accept the answer (click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in) as solution for your ask. This could be beneficial to other community members.

Comment: It looks like a great resource! Let me check if it provides annotations for all our use cases.

Comment: Gentle reminder, please accept the answer here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find:

- list of annotations supported for Azure Kubernetes services with type
  LoadBalancer:

https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/cloud-provider-azure/topics/loadbalancer/#loadbalancer-annotations

- list of Azure App Gateway Ingress controller kubernetes annotations:

https://azure.github.io/application-gateway-kubernetes-ingress/annotations/

Comment: These are great resources, thank you! Let me check if it provides annotations for all our use cases.